# Best way to use a web service for continuous uploading

Tags: c#, web-services

I have asked a similar question before and the answer I used for that does not work in this sligtly different scenario.

I have a winform desktop c# app.

Inside a timer (interval 100ms) I convert a bitmap to an array of bytes.

I have a stream of 10 bitmaps per scecond

These bytes are then uploaded to the server.

There are no issues with the server handling this.

On the client side I inovke the [web service] using async mehthods.

I am checking a condition that the [web service] cannot be invoked again until the previouse call has completed.

The frame/image is 'skipped' if the server does not respnd in time.

This is my client code:

```
     public void Init()
        {
            _live.StreamerCompleted += new wsLive.StreamerCompletedEventHandler(_live_StreamerCompleted);
        }

        private void _live_StreamerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _uploaded = true;
        }

 private static bool _uploaded = true;
private static wsLive.Live _live = new wsLive.Live();
  private static byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            imageIn.Dispose();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
  public static void AddFrame(Image<Bgr, Byte> _newFrame)
        {
            if (_newFrame != null && _uploaded)
            {
                byte[] _data = GetDeflated(_newFrame.Copy());
                _live.StreamerAsync(Shared.Alias, _data, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                _newFrame.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public static void AddFrame(Bitmap _newFrame)
        {
            byte[] _data = imageToByteArray(_newFrame);
            _live.StreamerAsync(Shared.Alias, _data, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            _newFrame.Dispose();
        }

    //declared at form load
    Init();

    //inside my timer...
    if (Uploaded)
    {
    LiveStreaming.AddFrame((Bitmap)_currentFrame.Clone());
    }
    _currentFrame.dispose();
```

But the memory climbs. Am I doing this right?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue that jumps out is that you aren't disposing of the MemoryStream in imageToByteArray.

Try this:

```
  private static byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            imageIn.Dispose();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this.Really appreciate it. You are quite right stream was not closed. I will see if that makes an impression :)

Comment: The RAM usage was hitting 80% before now it settles at 60% so definatley an improvement...